# Why this InnerHtml returning same output as innerText

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, innertext

(Beginner) The code below (css excluded) shows same output. But innerHtml should have given the output with html tag right?

HTML

```
    <div class="sunpath">
        <div class="sun"> SUN </div>
        <div class="planet">
           <div class="stable">
            Planet
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
p = document.querySelector(".sun");
console.log(p.innerHTML);
console.log(p.innerText);
```

In console (firefox) both gives the same output[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I found the solution. I made a dumb assumption. I mean, ofcourse they will return same output because, In the class ".Sun", the only thing present in there is the word SUN. Therefore both returns same thing. But for example if instead of just the word SUN, if we put <p>SUN</p>, then both returns different output !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right bro:
because u r accessing the parent tag:

if you have do this

```
   <div class="sun"><p> SUN </p></div>
```

then tag would be also console